# Does every stateful intermediate Stream API operation guarantee a new source collection?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is the following statement true?

> The `sorted()` operation is a “stateful intermediate operation”, which means that subsequent operations no longer operate on the backing collection, but on an internal state.

<sup>([Source](https://www.toptal.com/java/top-10-most-common-java-development-mistakes) and [source](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-friday-10-subtle) - they seem to copy from each other or come from the same source.)</sup>

**Disclaimer:** I am aware the following snippets are not legit usages of Java Stream API. Don't use in the production code.

I have tested [`Stream::sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--) as a snippet from sources above:

```
final List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    
list.stream()
    .filter(i -> i > 5)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(list::remove);

System.out.println(list);            // Prints [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

It works. I replaced [`Stream::sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--) with [`Stream::distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--), [`Stream::limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) and [`Stream::skip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-):

```
final List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    
list.stream()
    .filter(i -> i > 5)
    .distinct()
    .forEach(list::remove);          // Throws NullPointerException
```

To my surprise, the `NullPointerException` is thrown.

All the tested methods follow the [stateful intermediate operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) characteristics. Yet, this unique behavior of [`Stream::sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--) is not documented nor the [Stream operations and pipelines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) part explains whether the *stateful intermediate operations* really guarantee a new source collection.

Where my confusion comes from and what is the explanation of the behavior above?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but for general stream advice: This may not be the best example, because with Streams it makes more sense to do something like `List<Integer> newList = list.stream().filter(...).collect(...);` then use the result of the stream (`newList`) from there on. Streams are much easier to grasp if you think about them as functions that return a result (whether it is modified or created new) that you may further operate on, not the original source. Then you shouldn't (in most cases) have to worry about implementation details like this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The API documentation makes no such guarantee “that subsequent operations no longer operate on the backing collection”, hence, you should never rely on such a behavior of a particular implementation.

Your example happens to do the desired thing by accident; there’s not even a guarantee that the `List` created by `collect(Collectors.toList())` supports the `remove` operation.

To show a counter-example

```
Set<Integer> set = IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
set.stream()
    .filter(i -> i > 5)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(set::remove);
```

throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`. The reason is that the implementation optimizes this scenario, as the source is already sorted. In principle, it could do the same optimization to your original example, as `forEach` is explicitly performing the action in no specified order, hence, the sorting is unnecessary.

There are other optimizations imaginable, e.g. `sorted().findFirst()` could get converted to a “find the minimum” operation, without the need to copy the element into a new storage for sorting.

So the bottom line is, when relying on unspecified behavior, what may happen to work today, may break tomorrow, when new optimizations are added.

Comment: @Nikolas well, that blog is focusing on observed behavior and looking at the code, where it should have referred to the specification instead. But at least the conclusion is basically correct: “*we can only suggest that you never actually do modify a backing collection while consuming a stream*”.

Answer (score 8):

Well `sorted` has to be a full *copying* barrier for the stream pipeline, after all your source could be *not sorted*; but this is not documented as such, thus do not rely on it.

This is not *just* about `sorted` per-se, but what other optimization can be done to the stream pipeline, so that `sorted` could be entirely skipped. For example:

```
List<Integer> sortedList = IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    StreamSupport.stream(() -> sortedList.spliterator(), Spliterator.SORTED, false)
            .sorted()
            .forEach(sortedList::remove); // fails with CME, thus no copying occurred
```

Of course, `sorted` needs to be a full barrier and stop to do an entire sort, unless, of course, it can be skipped, thus the documentation makes no such promises, so that we don't run in weird surprises.

`distinct` on the other hand does not *have to be a full barrier*, all distinct does is check one element at a time, if it is unique; so after a single element is checked (and it is unique) it is passed to the next stage, thus without being a full barrier. Either way, this is not documented also...

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have brought up the cases with a terminal operation `forEach(list::remove)` because `list::remove` is an interfering function and it violates the ["non-interference"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference) principle for terminal actions.

It's vital to follow the rules before wondering why an incorrect code snippet causes unexpected (or undocumented) behaviour.

I believe that `list::remove` is the root of the problem here. You wouldn't have noticed the difference between the operations for this scenario if you'd written a proper action for `forEach`.

Comment: I am aware the first paragraph of your answer well, Andrew. Here I’d use Iterator or collect to a List to remove it all from the source. The second paragraph makes sence.

Comment: @Nikolas no one pointed that `list::remove` is inappropriate here. I wanted to highlight it.