# Can we throw two Exceptions by Streaming and mapping?

Tags: java, java-8

Actually I want to throw two exceptions as part of checking two conditions. But wondering how to throw these exceptions after streaming and mapping it.

This is the code to be converted to Java-8 Using Streams

```
  for(GroupCallCenter existingGroupCall : group.getGroupCallCenters())
   {
        if(!existingGroupCall.getCallCenter()
          .getId().equals(accountCallCenterResource.getCallCenterId())) 
            {
             if(!accountCallCenterResource.getValidity().getEffectiveStarting().isAfter(existingGroupCall.getExpirationDate())&&!existingGroupCall.getEffectiveDate().isAfter(accountCallCenterResource.getValidity().getExpiresAfter())) 
               {
                 throw new ApiException(ApiErrorCode.DEFAULT_400, "Group call 
                     center already exist for that period");
                  }
       }
  else {
         throw new DuplicateException(ApiErrorCode.DUPLICATE, 
         existingGroupCall.getId());   
       }
   }
```

Comment: you can only throw one Exception at a time. you can, however, build a list with errors and return that, or add that to an Exception you throw

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you asking about converting your looping to stream operations?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to convert the looping to streams and throw the exceptions then and there

Comment: Your code is hard enough to read without the haphazard indentation. Perhaps you would like to fix it.

Comment: What is the reason behind conversion to [tag:java-stream]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just apply the simple stream forEach like below:

```
group.getGroupCallCenters().stream().forEach((existingGroupCall) ->
           {
               if(!existingGroupCall.getCallCenter()
              .getId().equals(accountCallCenterResource.getCallCenterId())) 
             {
               if 
              (!accountCallCenterResource.getValidity().getEffectiveStarting()
                    .isAfter(existingGroupCall.getExpirationDate())
                    && !existingGroupCall.getEffectiveDate()                      

       .isAfter(accountCallCenterResource.getValidity().getExpiresAfter())) 
                   {
               throw new ApiException(ApiErrorCode.DEFAULT_400, "Group call center already exist for that period");
                      }
           }
            else {
                throw new DuplicateException(ApiErrorCode.DUPLICATE, 
          existingGroupCall.getId());   
                }
            });
```

You have not mention what is `accountCallCenterResource` object in your code. You have to make sure that `accountCallCenterResource` is final or effectivaly final to use it inside the stream method.

For more detailed understanding you can refer [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_streams.htm)

Comment: Why not `group.getGroupCallCenters().forEach()` directly? What benefit it provides? The [tag:java-stream] should **not** be used like this.

Comment: @Nikolas, We can even use the `group.getGroupCallCenters().forEach()`. But He wanted to use it using stream. SO i kept it like this

Comment: Again, what is the benefit? You might want to read [What is difference between Collection.stream().forEach() and Collection.forEach()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218874/what-is-difference-between-collection-stream-foreach-and-collection-foreach) to get proved why your approach violates the [tag:java-stream] principles.

Comment: I don’t understand your rage - do you have a reason to downvote my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272533/java-8-stream-api-does-any-stateful-intermediate-operation-guarantee-a-new-sou) because you don’t disagree with my comment?